# trying to format pandas.to_datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm trying to get today's date in a few different formats and I keep getting errors:

```
pd.to_datetime('Today',format='%m/%d/%Y') + MonthEnd(-1)

ValueError: time data 'Today' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

What is the correct syntax to get todays date in yyyy-mm-dd and yyyymm formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For YYYY-MM-DD format, you can do this:

```
import datetime as dt

print(dt.datetime.today().date())

2017-05-23
```

For YYYY-MM format, you can do this:

```
print(dt.datetime.today().date().strftime('%Y-%m'))

2017-05
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this on just a few columns you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe_name['Date_Column_name'].apply(pd.tslib.normalize_date)
```

This method doesn't use any other module except pandas. If you need a "custom" date format you can always do:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dataframe_name['Date_Column_name'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Here is a list of [strftime options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).